# Нужно ли ставить цифры в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, число, цифры

Нужны ли кавычки при сочетаниях: *`цифра («)1(»), число («)144(»)`*?

Мне кажется, что нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, в таких сочетаниях кавычки не нужны. Цифры и числа уже сами по себе выделяются в тексте.

> [**Вопрос № 305027**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=305027)
> Очень нужна ваша помощь! Какое правило использовать — берется ли здесь в кавычки цифра «1»? <На подставке фигурки была цифра «5».> А в таком случае: <На подставке фигурки нашли число «555».>?
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Кавычки не требуются: *цифра 5, число 555, цифра пять.*